# LoggerInterface in Shopware 6.5.4.1 does no longer log to custom file

Tags: shopware, shopware6

with the new Version of Shopware 6.5.4.1 I got small issue with the LoggerFactory (https://sindhitutorials.com/pages/shopware-6-custom-plugin-logger)

Till the update it was so that for Plugin to own its own .log File in `var/log`.
Now with this update everything is logged within `dev.log` and there it gets its own Channel displayed.

`services.xml` looks like this:

```
<service id="Company\PluginName\Core\Util\Logger" class="Monolog\Logger">
    <factory service="Shopware\Core\Framework\Log\LoggerFactory" method="createRotating" />
    <argument type="string">Company_PluginName</argument>
</service>
```

Comment: Which Shopware version did you use before where it was working? You can checkout https://github.com/shopware/platform/ for any Logger related commits or package updates between to both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do move the log in a separate file creating the following services

```
<service id="company.plugin.logger" class="Monolog\Logger">
    <argument type="string">Company_PluginName</argument>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument type="service" id="company.plugin.rotatingHandler"/>
    </argument>
</service>

<service id="company.plugin.rotatingHandler" class="Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler">
    <argument type="string">%kernel.logs_dir%/company-name-%kernel.environment%.log</argument>
</service>
```

One service that extends the default `RotatingFileHandler`, here you provide a the location of your log file `%kernel.logs_dir%/company-name-%kernel.environment%.log` then you use that service as a parameter for your `Monolog\Logger` service

Comment: Try avoiding (almost) pure-code answers. Would be nice to describe why this works / is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me as well on SW 6.5.6.0. Note that the service id may also be a simpler name, like `<service id="company.plugin.logger"...`, which then does not look as if these ids require a class file.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is likely related to this change:

> Logging of extensions
> Monolog instances of extensions consider now the project-wide configured Monolog handler.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/discussions/3254

So please check the project wide logger which is used now - so the behavior you are seeing is intended.

If you really need a separate logger, you need to create the service as @madalinivascu described.

Comment: this is more of a comment than a answer